# ArgumentException The type DummyTracer must derive from ITraceWriter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, trace

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Web.Http.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The type DummyTracer must derive from ITraceWriter.
```

The funny thing is... the DummyTraceWriter is specified in the same project.
It looks like that:

```
namespace Company.Project.Logic
{
    using System;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Web.Http.Tracing;

    public class DummyTracer : ITraceWriter
    {
        public void Trace(HttpRequestMessage request, string category, TraceLevel level, Action<TraceRecord> traceAction)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Looks good right? Well... can't register my new type.

```
httpConfiguration.Services.Replace(typeof(ITraceWriter), new DummyTracer());
```

fails with the error message mentioned earlier: The type DummyTracer must derive from ITraceWriter.

Answer (score 0):

Fun fact.

The problem is **NOT** the actual DummyTraceWriter but rather the **ITraceWriter interface** I am trying to replace.

```
httpConfiguration.Services.Replace(typeof(ITraceWriter), new DummyTracer());
```

Somehow this was ITraceWriter from Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization rather than System.Web.Http.